# phonegap media success callback not fire

Tags: cordova, callback, phonegap-plugins, media, recording

My phonegap version is 5.1.1
i used plugin media and file

I did work media recording 
it works well 
but onSuccess callback not fire

```
var name = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess() {  //not fire 
    alert("recordAudio():Audio Success");
}
```

I want to process

1. `name.startRecord();`
2. `name.stopRecord();`
3. mydevice save after callback